# InitializeComponent does not exist in the current context error

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm getting this error on my Xamarin.Forms project whenever I try to create a Page with XAML+CS.

The namespace on the file corresponds:
[image: namespaces]

And I've set the build action of the XAML Page to `EmbeddedResource` with the Custom Tool `MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml`.
I checked the .csproj and it sets correctly the build action:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="AppCore\Pages\SettingsPage.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
```

And:

```
<Compile Include="AppCore\Pages\SettingsPage.xaml.cs">
<DependentUpon>SettingsPage.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Cleaning the solution and deleting the obj/bin folders didn't help and neither reinstalling the packages via `update-package -project Travlendar.Core -reinstall`.

This is SettingsPage:

```
using Travlendar.Core.AppCore.ViewModels;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Travlendar.Core.AppCore.Pages
{
    public partial class SettingsPage : ContentPage
    {
        public SettingsPage (INavigation navigation)
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            BindingContext = new SettingsViewModel (this, navigation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your `SettingsPage.xaml.cs` contain?

Comment: try closing settingspage.xaml.cs before building.  Not sure why it helps but it does.

Comment: @SushiHangover added the code to the question, but there isn't anything special..

Comment: @KenTucker same behaviour as before..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, I had to delete the `packages` folder in the solution.
Then cleaning/re-building the solution and everything is working back.